# How much of __constant__ memory is cached (CUDA)

Tags: cuda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the constant memory size limited in CUDA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256402/why-is-the-constant-memory-size-limited-in-cuda)

I understand that `__constant__` memory has a cache, but I'm not clear if all of `__constant__` memory is cached.

It doesn't appear as though `__constant__` data goes directly to cache.  Literature: It only goes to cache if it is read by a kernel.  This implies the cache size is smaller than the `__constant__` mem size.  My guess is that `__constant__` mem is just global memory with cache support.  (True?)

If my deviceProp.totalConstMem = 64KB.  Does this mean I have a 64KB cache supporting it?  Would this be L1 or L2 cache?  Is this cache at all related to deviceProp.l2CacheSize?

Comment: It's just like a normal CPU cache - call it L1 if you like, but since there's only one cache for constant memory then the 1 is redundant. The constant memory itself is just a chunk of DRAM but it's not mapped into the same address space as global memory.

Comment: This thread may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256402/why-is-the-constant-memory-size-limited-in-cuda

Comment: It depends of your nvidia card and compute capability, search in the specifications of the cuda toolkit.